# Chrome Devtools: move network panels one above the other

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I'm struggling to get the Google Chrome Devtools Network panels the proper way. When the devtools sidepanel is narrow, the network panels do not move from side-by-side view (see screenshot) to one-above-the-other view.
Any idea on how to solve this display issue ?
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unequivocally a bug in devtools, which you can report in https://crbug.com.

Comment: I reported the Devtools issue :
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1502786